# Studies of less privileged groups, different racial or cultural groups around the world. Not a right sentence?

Tags: sentence

There is an sentence in the [website](https://english.elpais.com/science-tech/2023-04-17/robert-waldinger-psychiatrist-happiness-depends-on-what-were-lacking.html):

> Studies of less privileged groups, different racial or cultural groups around the world.

I can't find a verb in this sentence. This is not a completed sentence. Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a fragment.  It is a noun phrase.

This comes from a transcript of a an interview, and this kind of disordered speech is common when you transcribe speech. These kind of fragments are often the speaker just giving an example by naming it.  So look at the context:

> But many other teams have found the same in different investigations. Studies of less....

The speaker is giving examples of the kind of studies that other have done. You could make a sentence by inserting "There are" at the start of the fragment.